# Proxy Setup Unsuccessful

Tags: raspbian, wifi, linux, raspbian-jessie, ethernet

I have done proxy setup (both /etc/environment and /etc/apt/apt.conf) still cannot connect to internet neither through WIFI nor Ethernet. Please help its urgent.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that `apt` uses the HTTP proxy environment variables, and the issue you're having is that you can't fetch anything during install from the Internet:

```
export http_proxy=10.0.0.1:80
export https_proxy=10.0.0.1:80
```

...and then try `apt` again.

Comment: Ya I have done but it did not work...what are the other possibilities

Comment: Setting HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY. But are you even online? Ping your gateway and proxy.

Comment: Yes I had done it writing like ping www.yahoo.com.It says 5 packets send 0 received something like that. Ok I can install packages using terminal now but still can't have an access to the internet through the browser.